# SwfUpload give 302 error when upload images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip, swfupload, csrf-protection

I am using swfUpload plugin with paperclip which use flash to upload images but when i press

upload button it give me this error and image are not upload and not save in DB.It show this 
error.

alexa's-lace-waist-yoga-pants-size4.jpg          //this is my image for upload

Upload Error: 302                                //this is error

any useful help will be most appreciated.

this is log output

Started POST "/admin/images/create_banner_image" for 202.154.225.30 at 2012-03-14 02:19:34 -0400
  Processing by Admin::ImagesController#create_banner_image as HTML
  Parameters: {"Filename"=>"alexa's-lace-waist-yoga-pants-size4.jpg", "Filedata"=>#>, "Upload"=>"Submit Query"}
WARNING: Can't verify CSRF token authenticity
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 42ms

Now please answer @shinghara

Comment: Can you paste the complete log output ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want a quick hack, then adding

```
protect_from_forgery :except => :create_banner_image
```

to your Admin::ImagesController class should help.

If you want to implement a secure solution - it'll require a bit more work. SWFupload uses flash, and it doesn't know anything about your Rails session unless you tell it. See good guide on how to fix it here: [Rails 2.3.4 and SWFUpload – Rack Middleware for Flash Uploads that Degrade Gracefully](http://jetpackweb.com/blog/2009/10/21/rails-2-3-4-and-swfupload-rack-middleware-for-flash-uploads-that-degrade-gracefully/)

Answer (score 1):

I used new version of swfupload and hence fixed the problem.